# how to execute if statement line by line in bash

Tags: bash

how to execute if statement line by line in bash??

```
for i in $(cat $install_script)
do
    if [ "$i" = "$check" ]; then
        count=$((count+1))
        echo whiptail --title "Install SmartBoard" --yesno "${scripts_name[$count]}" 7 $((${#scripts_name[$count]} + 5))
        if (( $? == 0 )); then
            skip=false
        else
            skip=true
        fi
    fi
    if [ "$i" == "$check wifi" ]; then
        break
    fi
    if [ $skip == true ]; then
        continue
    else
        sh -c $i ## process line by line
    fi
done
```

error !!

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "then")

sh: 1: Syntax error: "then" unexpected

sh: 1: Syntax error: "else" unexpected

sh: 1: Syntax error: "fi" unexpected
```

i'm not good english so if my posts word be rude Sorry that. :(

Comment: Please give a minimal example of the input file that reveals these syntax errors.

Comment: Do you mean debugging the script line by line? In that case do this `sh -x youscript.sh`. Would be great if you can provide some more information.

Comment: @user803422    
in line by line install scriptv variable this
intsall_script="./install.sh"
check="#### check line by line"

install.sh file crawling this page :  https://github.com/anhive-junior/smart-board/wiki/Install-Smart-Board

Comment: I understand that you have a full script that you want to execute but jumping over some lines. That's why you go over all of them and don't want to execute the ones that equal your "$check". But your problem is that sh creates a subshell, so if it executes the line of an "if", and the corresponding"then" is in another line, it won''t recognize it. My best solution to this would be to use sed to substitute in the original script all the lines that equal to "$check" for a blank character, for example.

Comment: @Mihir no debugging l want execution command line by line

Comment: You can run the if statements one by one on the command line and see if you can find the error.

Comment: copy/paste your code into https://shellcheck.net .You'll need a "she-bang" line as the first line, usually `#!/bin/bash` .  If  it doesn't flag any error messages then clean up your file with `dos2unix myScript` .

Comment: Your whole approach is fundamentally flawed. Reading a script line by line and then running those lines one at a time will never work. As you've discovered, there are many constructs, such as `if` blocks, that can't be broken apart into individual lines. You need to rethink the whole thing.

Comment: @shellter  

I excluded "she-bang" Because it is a partial code,

Comment: @Miki4444 i just want process shell command one by one T_T no excluded if statements

Comment: @Yonghoon I know man, but you can't. You either change the original script to delete what you don't want or execute the script by indivisible blocks. Sorry.

Comment: @JohnKugelman no solution T_T?

Comment: Thank u everyone. :D    i have to find another solution!!